# libCURL Multipart POST with a large file

Tags: post, libcurl, large-files, large-file-upload

I need to upload a large file (>2 GB) using multipart POST request. Source file can be named using unicode symbols. The problem is that libcurl does not support unicode wfopen in windows, so I am not able to complete this task in usual way like

```
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr,
  CURLFORM_COPYNAME, fieldname,
  CURLFORM_FILENAME, filename,
  CURLFORM_FILE, full_path_to_file,
  CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "application/octet-stream",
  CURLFORM_END);
```

I figured out that I can use a CURLFORM_STREAM option of curl_formadd in conjunction with CURLOPT_READFUNCTION. Now I need to manually set the file size through CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH option, but it accepts only "long" as a parameter when I need to set a "long long" file size. After a look through curl manual I found some CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE option, but it does nothing in my case. It seems that multipart request system ignores this parameter. I don't know what to do, I don't want to give up unicode names or large files support.

Comment: I would suggest you roll up your sleeves and consider which source code change that would give you the feature the best way, then suggest that change to the libcurl team...

Comment: It seems this is the only way to make it work.